# Problems with hiding nodes

Tags: tree, edges, jung

I'm making Decision Tree, and I want to draw it using Tree. My idea is to make it like simulation. When user clicks Next, it will show him next node, and so on. So basically, I need to unhide nodes interactively (they will be hidden by default).

```
private Forest<TreeNode, TreeLink> g;
g = new SparseTree<TreeNode, TreeLink()>;
```

Than, I'm adding Vertex - root and Edges:

```
g.addVertex(root);
TreeLink v = new TreeLink(50, 75);
g.addEdge(v, node.parent, node, EdgeType.DIRECTED);
```

I made `TreeNodePredicate` and `TreeLinkPredicate`, and inserted logic for hiding/unhiding Nodes/Links. If I say

```
 v.setVisible(false);
```

everything will work fine, and edge/edges will be hidden. But if I say

```
node.setVisible(false);
```

Noting happens. My tree will be displayed with all nodes unhidden - Edges will be hidden.
I'm guessing that this is not the right way to hide Nodes. I know that some JUNG classes have `addChild()` method (there is no `addChild()` here) - maybe, the key is to use that method, or something different from `SparseTree`?

Comment: You're asking what the problem is with a class whose behaviors you haven't defined (TreeNode/TreeLink).  This makes it hard to answer your question.  Also, have you looked at the built-in mechanisms for hiding vertices and edges?

Comment: Thank you Joshua for your comment
Could you give me link to resources where I could find information about built-in mechanism for hidding. I'm little lost and there is no plenty documentation about JUNG

Comment: I'd start with the documentation link on the JUNG website: http://jung.sf.net/doc/index.html and then I'd look at the various samples (source in the distribution, applets on the website for most of them) at least one of which demonstrates hiding (PluggableRendererDemo).

Comment: Thanks Joshua, i founded solution - and now, I complettely understand how it works. Also, I saw that you are developing JUNG - great job and i wish you all the best.